# Domain Controller returns LDAP Referral for it's own domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ldap, domain-controller

I have 2 domains, each with 2 Domain Controllers:

- company.local
- ad.company.com.au

Both domains are in the same forest and have a bi-direction trust setup. We're migrating to the `ad.company.com.au` at present, however having some issues with systems that need to query LDAP.

When doing an LDAP search against either Domain Controller in `ad.company.com.au` we get a referral to `company.com.au` which is NOT under AD control:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -h 172.xx.xx.11 -b DC=company,DC=com,DC=au -D "my.username@ad.company.com.au" -W
Enter LDAP Password: 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <DC=company,DC=com,DC=au> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
# with manageDSAit control
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 10 Referral
text: 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007EF, data 0, 1 access points
    ref 1: 'company.
 com.au'

ref: ldap://company.com.au/DC=company,DC=com,DC=au

# numResponses: 1
```

Note the referral points to `company.com.au` which AD does NOT control -- the domain is `ad.company.com.au` and it is delegated by the `company.com.au` nameservers to the 2 DC's.

Querying the Global Catalog on the same server gives us the results we expect.

So why would the Domain Controller for a domain not know about the domain in it's LDAP, while the GC does know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you are specifying company.com.au as the search base.  If you want to query your domain local partition without getting a referral, use ad.company.com.au as your search base.

Comment: Oh my... 3 of us looked at this and none of us saw that. Thank-you for being our eyes, we'll go get them checked out at the optometrist now.